# Making aggregation more efficient in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have two dataframes in this problem I want to add a column to loan_df which aggregates across recharge_df. So for each loan given, I want to get the borrower's mean recharges prior to the date the loan was taken (in this case 90 days prior). I will then add this new column to loan_df. My code below works but is slow. Any ideas on how to make it super efficient?

```
def mean_rec_func(msisdn,date,advance_id,window, name):
"""Returns mean recharges within a specified number of days prior to loan being taken
Keyword Arguments:
msisdn -- APF_MSISDN for loan (this is like customer ID)
date -- APF_DATE on which loan taken
advance_id -- APF_ADVANCE_ID for loan
window -- number of days to look back(int)
name -- name of the newly computed stat
"""
mean_rec = recharge_df.loc[(recharge_df['APF_MSISDN'] == msisdn) &
                          (recharge_df['APF_DATE']<date)
                          & (recharge_df['APF_DATE']>=date - datetime.timedelta(days = window))
                          ]['APF_AMOUNT'].mean()
return pd.Series([advance_id,msisdn,mean_rec], index=['APF_ADVANCE_ID', 'APF_MSISDN', name])
# Mean recharge over last 90 days
mean_recharge_90 = loan_df.apply(lambda row: mean_rec_func(row['APF_MSISDN'], row['APF_DATE'],
                                                         row['APF_ADVANCE_ID'],
                                                         window = 90,
                                                         name ="MEAN_RECHARGE_90"), axis = 1)
```

EDIT:
[image: Desired Output]

Comment: Please provide a **[mcve]**. Here that means fix your code indentation, provide some input data, show your current/desired output for that input data. No images/links, just text.

Answer (score 0):

Consider an SQL solution as your logic translates into the following query with a correlated aggregate subquery (which admittedly is also an expensive type of query as aggregates are run for every outer query row, similar to pandas `apply` loop).

```sql
SELECT l.*, 
       (SELECT AVG([APF_AMOUNT]) FROM recharge_df r
        WHERE r.[APF_DATE] >= date(l.[APF_DATE], '-90 day') 
          AND r.[APF_DATE] < l.[APF_DATE]
          AND r.[APF_MSISDN] = l.[APF_MSISDN]) AS mean_recharge_90
FROM loan_df l
```

In pandas, you can use the [`pandasql`](https://github.com/yhat/pandasql) module which runs an in-memory instance to SQLite:

```
from pandasql import sqldf

pysqldf = lambda q: sqldf(q, globals())

sql = """SELECT l.*, 
            (SELECT AVG([APF_AMOUNT]) FROM recharge_df r
             WHERE r.[APF_DATE] >= date(l.[APF_DATE], '-90 day') 
               AND r.[APF_DATE] < l.[APF_DATE]
               AND r.[APF_MSISDN] = l.[APF_MSISDN]) AS mean_recharge_90
         FROM loan_df l"""

output_df = pysqldf(q)
```

Below is the expanded version which runs under the hood of `pandasql`, interfacing to SQLAlchemy and pandas' import/export calls: `read_sql` and `to_sql`.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

# IN-MEMORY DATABASE (NO PATH SPECIFIED)
engine = create_engine('sqlite://')

# EXPORT DATAFRAMES
recharge_df.to_sql("recharge_tbl", con=engine, if_exists='replace')
loan_df.to_sql("loan_tbl", con=engine, if_exists='replace')

sql = """SELECT l.*, 
            (SELECT AVG([APF_AMOUNT]) FROM recharge_tbl r
             WHERE r.[APF_DATE] >= date(l.[APF_DATE], '-90 day') 
               AND r.[APF_DATE] < l.[APF_DATE]
               AND r.[APF_MSISDN] = l.[APF_MSISDN]) AS mean_recharge_90
         FROM loan_tbl l"""

# IMPORT QUERY RESULT
output_df = pd.read_sql(strSQL, engine)

# IN-MEMORY DATABASE DESTROYED
engine.dispose()
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, it won't solve the problem. The issue is that I am working with 2 dataframes and I need the aggregation across recharge_df to be relative to the date in loan_df.

Comment: See revamped solution using SQL. Maybe there is a performance gain using a query engine.